# What happens to TimeZoneInfo if a country changes it's Daylight savings settings?

Tags: c#, datetime, time, timezone

In .Net there is a `TimeZoneInfo` class that can convert `DateTime`s from one TZ to another and it does so with daylight savings in mind.

I'm guessing , internally, .Net is just hardcoded with all the data about when daylight savings starts and ends.

My question is - if I have an app that uses `TimeZoneInfo` to convert between TZs and a certain country changes it's daylight savings setting (or "policy" or whatever humans call it) the only way to reflect that change in my app would be to manually set a check for that country or apply some .Net update?

In addition, since Daylight Savings is per country and `TimeZoneInfo` works with Time Zones, how do I tell it to convert a time with a specific country in mind? I can only see a constructor that takes a timezone ID.

Comment: Daylight savings is not "per country". It can also depend on where you are in a country, not just the country. One country can have many timezones! "I can only see a constructor that takes a timezone ID." Is that not enough?

Comment: @Sweeper, it very much is "per country", as it is the country that decides whether they will have DS or not, not the time zone. So, no, it is not enough. Maybe I need to clarify - there can also be (shockingly) many countries per time zone.

Comment: In United States, it is per state.  In Arizona, for example, while the state does not use DST, Native American reservations in the state do.

Comment: Australia is another example. Some states observe DST, others don’t. I can’t tell you which ones do and don’t off the top of my head though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the package, the time zone data comes from your OS so the package will update when the OS is updated.  This is how SQL server works as well.  For example, the US Congress changed DTS in the mid 2000's we had to release a Windows update to customers to make sure our code ran with the correct time.  Some NuGet libraries have to be updated whenever this happens.  For example, [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter) gets updated when a time zone changes.

Note:  DTS and time zones are controlled by laws so there is no algorithm or formula for determining them.  Some areas of the United States, Hawaii and Arizona (but not all of it), don't have DTS at all.